# 2 different lock screens -> 1 lock screen

Tags: lock-screen

I have 2 different lock screens. 1 with option to change the user and another 1 without this option.
The 1 with the option is when I lock the screen from the top bar and the other 1 is when I close the lid.

I want that in both cases (top bar lock and lid lock), the lock screen will be the 1 with the option of changing user.

Thanks!

edit:
Using Ubuntu 18.04.2

I don't have option to log in as another user. I have box with editText (for the password) and a button, to release the lock.

photos of the different lock screens.

[image]

[image: The button says "release"]

I also tried some commands to change the behaviour when the lid close. It turn-off, suspend (bring me to the lock screen, without the option), lock (bring me to the lock screen, without the option) and some other things. but none of them suspend the computer and bring me to the lock screen with the option of changing user.

Btw, is there a way to get a message when anyone post reply in here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90980/discussion-on-question-by-user9047495-2-different-lock-screens-1-lock-screen).

Comment: I know, but I can get there only by pressing the button in the top bar. when i close the lid, i cant change user, turn-off the computer or do anything else but login back. I can't even change keyboard layout.